# Finding out whether a website returns 200

Tags: php, validation, get-headers

I was using the following code to check whether a link that a user provides really points to an existing website:

```
$headers=get_headers($imageurl);
if (strpos($headers[0], '200') === false) {
    echo "not valid1";
    exit;
}
```

As test, I use the img http://cdn.thegloss.com/files/2012/04/stormtr.jpg

As long as I use this on my localhost, it works fine - i.e. it said that the url is valid and did not echo "not valid1" - now it is on a different server and it echoes "not valid1". How come? Anybody any idea?

Thanks!
Dennis

Comment: This is working ok for me. What does it look like if you `var_dump($headers)`?

Comment: @Travesty3 It gives me bool(false) - what does that mean?

Comment: According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php), `get_headers` "Returns an indexed or associative array with the headers, or FALSE on failure." So it sounds like it failed somehow. Perhaps a firewall issue?

Comment: Is your server allowed to access the internet? Is it behind a proxy?

Comment: It was because allow_url_fopen was disabled. THanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_headers()` returns false because it failed.
It might be because `allow_url_fopen` is set to Off on the server.

Comment: +1.  I was thinking the same thing, but the documentation isn't exactly clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will return only the 3-digit HTTP response code

```
function get_response_code($theURL) {
    $headers = get_headers($theURL);
    return substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
}
```

Comment: It was because allow_url_fopen was disabled. THanks!